# UINavigationController does not release memory after back button is tapped

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

I have a mainViewController and a secondViewController.  The SecondViewController is pushed using segue (iOS 7 app).
The problem is that when the back button is tapped and the app is back to mainViewController, the secondViewController memory is not released.

In prepareforSegue, I don't do any allocation.  I merely set the delegate for the SecondViewController (aka cvc below).  The CollectionViewController (aka SecondViewController) is quite big so as the user goes back-and-forth between the main VC and the SecondViewController memory usage keeps increasing and the app crashes eventually.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Gallery"]) {
    CollectionViewController *cvc =  (CollectionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    cvc.delegate = self;
}
}
```

Also, the delegate is a weak reference:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <collectionCellSelectedDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: Is the delegate a weak reference ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: The issue is something else. The SecondViewController get deallocated once you pop the view. ARC handles that part. The issue is somewhere else. May be something you are sending back through the delegate method which is causing it to crash. Please check your delegate method, because this definitely is not the issue.

Comment: are you setting the secondVC as a delegate somewhere?

Comment: Do you use a singleton somewhere that uses second view controller? Singletons sometimes can be nasty in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough information to localize the issue.

Are you sure `CollectionViewController` object is leaking? I mean it's possible that the issue is  caused by non-released sub-object used in `CollectionViewController` code. You can try Profiler Xcode Instrument to clarify it.

Also the issue may be caused by custom `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass (of course if you are using it).

Anyway, it would be great the take a look at storyboard and `CollectionViewController` code